# Documents Directory and Backups

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an application that uses Core Data, and I store images in the documents directory.  That works great, but I want to give the user the ability to export their data, then import their data through iTunes file sharing.

I not finding any great information about this, I want to backup images, and the Core Data database, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications that want to make user data files accessible can do so using application file sharing. File sharing enables the application to expose the contents of its /Documents directory to the user through iTunes. The user can then move files back and forth between the ios device  and a desktop computer.

To enable file sharing for your application, do the following:

Add the UIFileSharingEnabled key to your applications Info.plist file and set the value of the key to YES.

When the device is plugged into the users computer, iTunes  displays a File Sharing section in the Apps tab of the selected device.
The user can add files to this directory or move files to the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Add this key in your `info.plist`, then user will be able to save files from your document directory to their system using iTunes.

For more about this key [read the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW20)

 
A good tutorial is also there [**`How To Integrate iTunes File Sharing With Your iOS App`**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app)

[image]